# How to check if any item is being edited in the QTreeView or not?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I've subclassed a `QTreeView` and have overriden `keyPresseEvent()` to do stuff when certain keys are pressed. Naturally, I don't want to do that while an item is being edited. How can I check if editing is in progress or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check the  view's internal state to see if it is in editing state

```
if (my_treeview->state() != QAbstractItemView::EditingState)
{
   /* do some stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use these functions. If `edit` is called but `closeEditor` or  `editorDestroyed` is not called yet, it is in editing mode.

```
bool QAbstractItemView::edit ( const QModelIndex & index, EditTrigger trigger, QEvent * event ) [virtual protected]    
void QAbstractItemView::closeEditor ( QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemDelegate::EndEditHint hint ) [virtual protected slot]
void QAbstractItemView::editorDestroyed ( QObject * editor )   [virtual protected slot]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also helps me implement some other edit-related ideas of mine :) Totally missed those signals when reading the reference for QTreeView / QStandardItemModel.

Comment: Any chance for doing this without overriding protected methods? I'm asking because I'd like to do the same thing in `PyQt4` - where I can't re-implement protected functions as the ones above...